# Why does adding wp_footer or header stop my 404 pager rendering properly?

Tags: css, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have this basic 404 page on my local machine.

I've edited my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /wordpress/wp-content/themes/test_theme/404.php
```

The 404 page does works and opens fine, but when I add my `wp_head();` it breaks. The background-color still displays properly but the rest of the page fails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-gb'>
<head>
<title>404 Error</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-color: #111;
}

.board {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -250px;
  padding: 20px;
  font: 75px/75px Monoton, cursive;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red, 0 0 30px firebrick, 0 0 6px darkred;
  color: red;
}

#error {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px white, 0 0 30px green, 0 0 6px blue;
}

 </style>
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="board"><p id="error">error</p><p id="code">404</p></div>
<h2><?php _e( 'This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h2>
<p><?php _e( 'It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></p>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add some javascript via:

```
if(is_404()){               wp_register_script('404',get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.novacancy.min.js', false, NULL, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('404');
}
```

But adding `wp_footer();` also breaks the page, it's as though wordpress is breaking my 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading the theme file directly, which does not load all of the necessary WordPress files, and therefore functions.  Therefore, `wp_footer();` and `wp_header();` functions *do not exists*.

WordPress automatically takes care of 404 errors, so remove the line you've added to your .htaccess file, and it will start working properly.

Be sure to read this article: [Creating an Error 404 Page in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page)

Comment: Okay, but now I just get the standard 404 error message. I've checked out the wordpress 404 page, and I've tried using their example and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You just need to make it the same way you make all of your other pages. There is already a template - so just edit it instead of building a new page. You can just target that page, and put the CSS in your style.css with everything else.

Comment: @sheriffderek this is a custom theme, there is no 404 template as I haven't created one. If I do create a 404 page how do I then tell wordpress this page is my 404 page?

Comment: It will just know. I always make my themes from scratch too. If something is wrong, it searches through the pages, and finds a 404.php if there is one.

Comment: Also- that no-vacancy script is only about 4k or less. It's not worth the extra server request for page specific loading. Just put it will all of the other scripts.

Comment: I can be as simple as this, as long as you call it 404.php `<?php
/* Template name: 404 ERROR */
?><?php get_header(); ?><div class="container main-content" id="page-w" role="main">OOOPS!</div> <!-- .main-content --> <?php get_footer(); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

I think cale_b already answered you, but just to give more info, wp_head and get_footer is wordpress functions, so you can't call them without calling get_header, or include in the wp_blog_header.php.

If you just need the functions without getting the whole header (probably you want a customized header, or no header at all), I would recommend including wp_blog_header.php at the very top of your php file, or at least before any wordpress functions.

wp_blog_header.php can be found at the root directory of the wordpress installation.